# I'm getting an error invalid type cat3__c while Passing Values to JavaScript from Apex Controller Method

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

my vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="ActionFunctionDemoController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Action Function Demo" subtitle="Save a New Record"/>

    <apex:form >

        <apex:outputPanel id="jspanel"> 
            <script>  
                function onControllerReturn() 
                {
                    alert('{!message}')
                }
            </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:actionFunction name="doControllerSave" action="{!save}" rerender="jspanel"/>

        <apex:pageBlock id="blockSection">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton onclick="doControllerSave();" oncomplete="onControllerReturn()" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!cat.name}"/>  
                <apex:inputField value="{!cat.Cat2__c}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

 // Submit the form to successfully create a record. To generate an error, remove the value for 'Cat2' and save.

</apex:page>
```

my controller:

```
public with sharing class ActionFunctionDemoController 
{

    public Cat3__c cat {get;set;}
    public String message {get;set;}

    public ActionFunctionDemoController() 
    {
        cat = new Cat3__c(name='Some Value',Cat2__c='a0B70000002PuK2EAK');
        message = 'Try again!!'; // initial message.
    }

  public PageReference save() 
  { 
    try 
    {
        insert cat;
        message = 'Insert successful! -- ' + cat.id;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        message = 'Whoops! An error occurred -- ' + e.getMessage();      
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that your controller `message` property ends up wit the value "invalid type cat3__c" that gets displayed in the alert? Or does something else happen?

Comment: is the ID in `Cat2__c='a0B70000002PuK2EAK'` of the proper type (Cat2__c) or is it per chance of type Cat3__c?

Comment: does your profile has create access to the custom object Cat3__c ?

Comment: While i'm saving the controller in vf page only i'm getting this error..@KeithC

Comment: i jus wanna insert a new record by throwing the javascript message if it is successfully inserted and not...that doesn't matter with the ca2__c, delete the reference and give me the answer... if any solution would be appreciated..@crop1645

Comment: i've changed my code as you said vut still i'm getting invalid cat3__c  error..@crmprogdev

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you have these two getters/setters:

```
public Cat3__c cat {get;set;}
public String message {get;set;}
```

You clearly need the 2nd one for your JS pop up error message. In actuality, it only needs to be a setter since you're only setting it. Your controller never looks at it's existing value so doesn't need to `get` it.

Now, in your visualforce code, you do the following:

```
            <apex:inputField value="{!cat.name}"/>  
            <apex:inputField value="{!cat.Cat2__c}"/>
```

I don't see where you're doing a `get` on `name` or on `Cat2__c`; instead only on `cat`. It appears to me that you've hardcoded `Cat2__c` into your controller without doing a `get/set` on `name`.

If you want to continue to hardcode Cat2__c, I think you need at a minimum to add the following getter method:

```
public string name {get;}
```

In doing that, you'll need to change the following line of code to something like:

```
if(name.isEmpty() == false) cat = new Cat3__c(name='Some Value',Cat2__c='a0B70000002PuK2EAK');
```

Its up to you whether or not to add a getter for Cat2__c. I can see why its not necessary, but you *do* need to know whether there's a value for *both* of the two; something you don't appear to be doing in your logic as it stands right now unless you have a validation rule that applies to the fields on your VF page.

Since I don't know the full purpose of your controller or page, I won't comment further on your methods. I believe I've answered your question as asked.